# Python typehint int as positive

Tags: python, type-hinting

I am curious what would be the best way to specify that a type is not just a `int` but a positive `int` in Python.

**Examples:**

```py
# As function argument

def my_age(age: int) -> str:
    return f"You are {age} years old."


# As class property

class User:
    id: int
```

In both of these situations a negative value would be erroneous. It would be nice to be warned by my IDE/linter.

Is there a simple way to specify an integer as positive using type-hints?

Comment: Not in the type system. Write input validation/a property setter to reject negative values.

Comment: Do you want to make type checking or give type hinting?

Comment: @jonsharpe That was my first thought. Python does not have unsigned integers unless you use `ctypes`, and the type system deals with types not values. So it was a long shot. But glad to have it confirmed.

Comment: @Halil definitely type-hints.

Comment: You can make doc string

Comment: "specify […] a positive int".  "a negative value would be erroneous".  And zero?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Little late to the party but there is now a library called [annotated-types](https://github.com/annotated-types/annotated-types) that provides exactly what you want and is the 'official' way to go about this, per [PEP-593](https://peps.python.org/pep-0593/). So for your example of positive integers, you could make use of the built-in `typing.Annotated` and annotated-types' `Gt` predicate, like this:

```py
from typing import Annotated
from annotated_types import Gt


def my_age(age: Annotated[int, Gt(0)]) -> str:
    return f"You are {age} years old."


# As class property

class User:
    id: Annotated[int, Gt(0)]
```

Note that like all things related to type hints in Python, this doesn't actually enforce the constraint at runtime. If you want to enforce it you would still have to build assertions yourself.

Comment: A major use for type hints is documentation and the above is just plain ugly when read! It does seem to be a more flexible representation, but I would want to write +int, - int and just int to convey the meaning succinctly

Answer (score 9):

If you are using FastAPI, you can use `PositiveInt` from `pydantic`.

```py
from pydantic.types import PositiveInt


class Pizza:
    price: PositiveInt
```

Read more: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#pydantic-types

Comment: I mostly like this more than what I'd been doing:

`page: Annotated[int, Query(description="get page given other query parameters", ge=1)] = 1`.

I think I would keep it for instances like this though
    `page_size: Annotated[int, Query(description="set page window given other query parameters", ge=50, le=10_000)] = 50)]`

Answer (score 6):

My approach would be to define a `NewType`:

```
PositiveInt = NewType('PositiveInt', int)
```

and maybe a helper like:

```
def assert_positive(n: int) -> PositiveInt:
    assert n > 0
    return PositiveInt(n)
```

This isn't ironclad (because you can still say `PositiveInt(-5)` or something like that), but most typing can be overridden via casting anyway; just forcing that explicit declaration goes a long way to prevent most mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

This is a little bit around 2 corners, but if you use pydantic (for some reason), you have this built in

https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#constrained-types